# .NET get datatable rows using dynamic columns settings

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, stringbuilder

I have 2 datatables, `dt_columns` and `dt_rows`; `dt_columns` has a dynamic column of `dt_rows`. How can I retrieve/select data, fields from `dt_rows` using `IEnumerable<string>` in `dt_columns` and export it in a text file?

`dt_columns` datatable:

| header_name | custom_header_name |
| --- | --- |
| column1 | custom_header_1 |
| column2 | custom_header_2 |

`dt_rows` datatable:

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1.1 | Value1.2 |
| 2 | Value2.1 | Value2.2 |

Expected output in text file:

| custom_header_1 | custom_header_2 |
| --- | --- |
| Value1.1 | Value1.2 |
| Value2.1 | Value2.2 |

Here's a skeleton of what direction I was heading:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

DataTable dt_headers = new DataTable();
DataTable dt_rows = new DataTable();

using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data)) {
    dt_rows.Load(reader);
}

using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(headers)) {
    dt_headers.Load(reader);
}

IEnumerable<string> column_names = dt_headers.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                                .Select(row => (
                                                    row["custom_header_name"].ToString() == "" ? row["header_name"].ToString() : row["custom_header_name"].ToString()
                                                ));
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimeter, column_names));

foreach(DataRow row in dt_rows.Rows) {
     IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field =>
     String.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"")); 

     sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimeter, fields));
}

using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + "resources\\", file_name + ".txt")))
{
   output.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
   output.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @zaggler I want to iterate `dt_rows` data using `IEnumerable<string>` in `dt_columns` and append data in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
string[] colNames = dt_headers.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("header_name")).ToArray();
string[] custColNames = dt_headers.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("custom_header_name")).ToArray();

// build row values separated by the delimiter as strings
IEnumerable<string> data = dt_rows.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => string.Join(delimiter, colNames.Select(c => r.Field<string>(c))));
// prepend header(custom column names):
data = data.Prepend(string.Join(delimiter, custColNames));

// write to text-file
File.WriteAllLines(
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + "resources\\", file_name + ".txt"),
    data);
```

Comment: I think this would work but there's a possible that the `custom_header_name` is null so the column name should be `header_name`